# SQL to return seconds difference between two rows

Tags: sql-server

This question is related to SQL Server. I have the following table:

```
id    size   batch code   product code      additiontime
--------------------------------------------------------
1       91      55555       BigD Red        2017-05-15 13:00:00
2       91      55555       BigD Red        2017-05-15 13:00:05
3       94      55555       BigD Red        2017-05-15 13:00:15
4       91      44444       BigD Blue       2017-05-15 14:10:00
5       92      44444       BigD Blue       2017-05-15 14:15:00
6       93      44444       BigD Blue       2017-05-15 14:20:00
7       94      44444       BigD Blue       2017-05-15 14:30:00
8       91      33333       BigD Orange     2017-05-15 15:00:00
9       91      33333       BigD Orange     2017-05-15 15:00:10
10      94      33333       BigD Orange     2017-05-15 15:00:15
```

When I execute this SQL statement:

```
select *
from mytable y1
where size = 91 
  and not exists (select 1
                  from mytable y2
                  where y1.productcode = y2.productcode and y2.size = 92)
```

I get the following results:

```
id    size   batch code   product code      additiontime
--------------------------------------------------------
1       91      55555       BigD Red        2017-05-15 13:00:00
2       91      55555       BigD Red        2017-05-15 13:00:05
8       91      33333       BigD Orange     2017-05-15 15:00:00
9       91      33333       BigD Orange     2017-05-15 15:00:10
```

I'd like to modify the above query so that ONE row is shown per batch code, with an additional column added to show the difference in seconds between the first and second records of each batch code group, for example:

```
id    size   batch code   product code      additiontime            seconds difference
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       91      55555       BigD Red        2017-05-15 13:00:00     5
8       91      33333       BigD Orange     2017-05-15 15:00:00     10
```

I have tried the following SQL, which almost does the trick, but it returns multiple rows instead of just one per batch code:

```
WITH rows AS
(
    SELECT 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AdditionTime) AS rn 
    FROM 
        mytable y1
    WHERE
        size = 91 
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                        FROM mytable y2
                        WHERE y1.productcode = y2.productcode AND y2.size = 92)
)
SELECT DATEDIFF(second, mc.AdditionTime, mp.AdditionTime)
FROM rows mc
JOIN rows mp ON mc.rn = mp.rn - 1
```

My SQL knowledge is not great. I'm sure it's possible to produce the right results but I've tried all ways with no success. Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: do you always expect to have 2 rows to do a diff between or do you expect more? if so, how do you want to calculate the diff?

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2012 or higher, you can use [window functions](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/window-functions-in-sql-server/). With the over clause you can choose a previous row and do a proper DATEDIFF

Comment: @Tanner - always expect 2 rows.

Comment: @Pawel - thanks for mentioning this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives you the desired output with a self join on the result of the cte. Also, I added a `PARTITION BY` to the `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
CREATE TABLE #mytable
    (
      id INT ,
      size INT ,
      batchCode INT ,
      productCode NVARCHAR(30) ,
      additiontime DATETIME
    );


INSERT  INTO #mytable
        ( id, size, batchCode, productCode, additiontime )
VALUES  ( 1, 91, 55555, 'BigD Red', '2017-05-15 13:00:00' ),
        ( 2, 91, 55555, 'BigD Red', '2017-05-15 13:00:05' ),
        ( 3, 94, 55555, 'BigD Red', '2017-05-15 13:00:15' ),
        ( 4, 91, 44444, 'BigD Blue', '2017-05-15 14:10:00' ),
        ( 5, 92, 44444, 'BigD Blue', '2017-05-15 14:15:00' ),
        ( 6, 93, 44444, 'BigD Blue', '2017-05-15 14:20:00' ),
        ( 7, 94, 44444, 'BigD Blue', '2017-05-15 14:30:00' ),
        ( 8, 91, 33333, 'BigD Orange', '2017-05-15 15:00:00' ),
        ( 9, 91, 33333, 'BigD Orange', '2017-05-15 15:00:10' ),
        ( 10, 94, 33333, 'BigD Orange', '2017-05-15 15:00:15' );
WITH    rows
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY y1.batchCode ORDER BY additiontime ) AS rn
               FROM     #mytable y1
               WHERE    size = 91
                        AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                                         FROM   #mytable y2
                                         WHERE  y1.productCode = y2.productCode
                                                AND y2.size = 92 )
             )
    SELECT  t1.id ,
            t1.size ,
            t1.batchCode ,
            t1.productCode ,
            DATEDIFF(SECOND, t1.additiontime, t2.additiontime) SecondsDiff
    FROM    rows t1
            INNER JOIN rows t2 ON t2.batchCode = t1.batchCode
                                  AND t1.id != t2.id
    WHERE   t1.rn = 1; 

DROP TABLE #mytable
```

**Produces:**

```
id  size    batchCode   productCode  SecondsDiff
8   91      33333       BigD Orange  10
1   91      55555       BigD Red     5
```

Note, you should test with a larger data set to ensure accuracy and take account for any other scenarios.

Comment: @XavierAnimoto no problem

Answer (score 1):

You are actually quite close! :) 
The only missing thing is to add another condition on the `JOIN` of the `CTE`, so that you compare only rows with the same `product code` as below:

```
WITH rows AS
        (
          SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AdditionTime) AS rn 
          FROM mytable y1 
          WHERE size = 91 AND NOT EXISTS (
                                           SELECT *
                                           FROM mytable y2
                                           WHERE y1.productcode = y2.productcode and y2.size = 92)
         )
SELECT  mc.*, DATEDIFF(second, mc.AdditionTime, mp.AdditionTime) AS Diff
FROM    rows mc JOIN rows mp ON mc.rn = mp.rn - 1 AND mc.ProductCode = mp.ProductCode
```

*PS. Assuming that you know you have two rows per Product.*

Comment: thanks. I used Tanner's answer but yours did the job too.

Answer (score 1):

```
;With cte(id,size,batchcode,productcode,additiontime)
AS
(
SELECT 1 , 91, 55555,'BigD Red'   ,'2017-05-15 13:00:00' UNION ALL
SELECT 2 , 91, 55555,'BigD Red'   ,'2017-05-15 13:00:05' UNION ALL
SELECT 3 , 94, 55555,'BigD Red'   ,'2017-05-15 13:00:15' UNION ALL
SELECT 4 , 91, 44444,'BigD Blue'  ,'2017-05-15 14:10:00' UNION ALL
SELECT 5 , 92, 44444,'BigD Blue'  ,'2017-05-15 14:15:00' UNION ALL
SELECT 6 , 93, 44444,'BigD Blue'  ,'2017-05-15 14:20:00' UNION ALL
SELECT 7 , 94, 44444,'BigD Blue'  ,'2017-05-15 14:30:00' UNION ALL
SELECT 8 , 91, 33333,'BigD Orange','2017-05-15 15:00:00' UNION ALL
SELECT 9 , 91, 33333,'BigD Orange','2017-05-15 15:00:10' UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 94, 33333,'BigD Orange','2017-05-15 15:00:15' 
)
SELECT id
    ,size
    ,batchcode
    ,productcode
    ,additiontime
    ,(SecondDiff - LEADadditiontimeSec) AS secondsDifference
FROM (
    SELECT *
        ,DATEPART(SECOND, additiontime) LEADadditiontimeSec
        ,DATEPART(SECOND, LEADadditiontime) SecondDiff
    FROM (
        SELECT *
            ,LEAD(additiontime) OVER (
                PARTITION BY batchcode
                ,size ORDER BY batchcode
                ) LEADadditiontime
        FROM cte o
    WHERE size = 91
     AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM   cte i
                        WHERE  o.productCode = i.productCode
                        AND i.size = 92 )
        ) Dt
    ) Final
WHERE Final.SecondDiff IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 1
```

OutPut

```
id  size    batchcode   productcode  additiontime           secondsDifference
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   91      55555       BigD Red     2017-05-15 13:00:00        5
8   91      33333       BigD Orange  2017-05-15 15:00:00        10
```

Comment: Thanks. Wasn't sure about the UNION but looks to work. Have accepted Tanner's answer.

Comment: Hi i have used UNION All with cte for fetching data and acts a temp result set ,Union all is not used for your desired output

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully the following query will do the job for you -

```
SELECT id, size, [batch code], [product code], additiontime, DATEDIFF(SECOND, additiontime, next_addition_time) AS [seconds difference]
FROM
(
    SELECT *
        , LEAD(additiontime) OVER (PARTITION BY [batch code] ORDER BY additiontime) AS next_addition_time
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [batch code] ORDER BY additiontime) AS row_num
    FROM mytable
) AS t
WHERE row_num = 1;
```

First the sub-query puts a row number order by addition time for each batch. Also it stores the next value of addition time. The outer query then simply selects the first row and the difference between the current and next addition time.

Note that you should move the sub-query to a temporary table if the data is huge. Also you can do *ORDER BY* and give filters in the where clause.

Comment: thanks for adding the narrative to your example. haven't tried the SQL but will keep it in mind.

Comment: if the id and size is always in incremental order for a batch (addition time) than there is also a Single query solution without using any sub-queries / temporary tables. Let me know how it goes.