# SQL Server Iterate through CTE

Tags: sql-server, loops, cursor, common-table-expression, temp-tables

Stored procedure #1: `@Country` parameter returns 1+ rows of `OrganizationID` and `MeasurableID` columns

Stored procedure #2: `@OrganizationID` and `@MeasurableID` parameters, creates a CTE (which uses  `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Entities.ID ORDER BY Contracts.UTCmatched desc)` to return a separate row for each `Entity`)

I seek to combine these into a single stored procedure where the `@Country` param via the SP1 code returns (say 5) rows; each row is then iterated through the SP2 code to return a single table (of 100 rows if there are 20 Entities).

I've attempted both nested and recursive CTE's to no avail. I'm considering a loop/cursor and/or a populating final results into a temp table but frankly am a bit lost (and beyond my experience level) so would appreciate suggestions mostly about the approach to take.

Thanks in advance.

SP1

```
        SELECT
            dbo.Measurables.OrganizationID,
            dbo.Measurables.ID AS MeasurableID

            FROM dbo.Measurables INNER JOIN dbo.Organizations ON dbo.Organizations.ID = dbo.Measurables.OrganizationID

            WHERE   dbo.Measurables.EndUTC > SYSUTCDATETIME ( )  
                AND dbo.Measurables.OrganizationID IN
                                        (
                                                SELECT
                                                    dbo.Countries2Organizations.OrganizationID
                                                FROM
                                                    dbo.Countries2Organizations
                                                WHERE
                                                    dbo.Countries2Organizations.Sport IN 
                                                        (
                                                            SELECT
                                                                dbo.Countries2Sports.SportName
                                                            FROM
                                                                dbo.Countries2Sports
                                                            WHERE
                                                                dbo.Countries2Sports.CountryCode = @CountryCode
                                                        )
                                                AND (   dbo.Countries2Organizations.CountryCode = @CountryCode  OR dbo.Countries2Organizations.CountryCode = '')

                                        )

--Result:     OrganizationID     MeasurableID
                    --1                 2017
                    --1                 2018
                    --2                 2021
                    --3                 2023
```

SP2

```
;WITH 
        LastScore as ( SELECT Entities.ID, Results.Score,
                                 Results.UTC,   
                                row_number() over (partition by Entities.ID ORDER BY Results.UTC desc) row1
                            FROM dbo.Entities 
                                INNER JOIN dbo.Results ON dbo.Results.EntityID = dbo.Entities.ID
                            WHERE dbo.Results.MeasurableID = @MeasurableID),


        PreviousScore as ( SELECT Entities.ID,  Results.Score,
                                 Results.UTC,   
                                row_number() over (partition by Entities.ID ORDER BY Results.UTC desc) row2
                            FROM dbo.Entities 
                                INNER JOIN dbo.Results ON dbo.Results.EntityID = dbo.Entities.ID
                            WHERE dbo.Results.MeasurableID = @MeasurableID )



    SELECT @OrganizationID AS OrganizationID, @MeasurableID AS MeasurableID, Entities.ID AS EntityID,    
              LastScore.Score AS LastScore, 
                    LastScore.Score - PreviousScore.Score AS Change,    LastScore.UTC 

    FROM Entities 
            LEFT JOIN LastScore on LastScore.ID = Entities.ID AND row1=1
            LEFT JOIN PreviousScore on PreviousScore.ID = Entities.ID AND row2=2

    WHERE dbo.Entities.OrganizationID = @OrganizationID 



--Result:
 --OrganizationID   MeasurableID   EntityID   LastScore   Change   UTC   
      --1              2017           1          15          2    4/6/17
      --1              2017           1          18         -3    4/8/17
```

Comment: Can you please paste what your workings are currently please

Comment: Why SP, not functions?

Comment: yeah, a sample with dummy data and desired output will help both us and you understand the problem better

Comment: Take a look at this post of, which shows how you can present a re-runnable sample dataset for us to work with: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43998463/57475

Comment: @Tanner Functions is easier to return table data (nested insert..exec is not allowed, temp table is not good too)

Comment: using table functions you can achive your goal in one `select` query

Comment: Mike if you can paste your existing scripts, we can advise how it can be built up in stages

Comment: I will put a sample up asap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend use functions, not stored procedures
It works faster:

1) There no loops, data will be retrived in one query

2) with inline functions query optimizer can optimize entire query

Here is sample how to do this with functions:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Func1 (
    @Country    INT
)
RETURNS TABLE
RETURN
    SELECT
        dbo.Measurables.OrganizationID,
        dbo.Measurables.ID AS MeasurableID
    FROM dbo.Measurables
...

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Func2 (
    @OrganizationID  INT,
    @MeasurableID    INT
)
RETURNS TABLE
RETURN
    WITH 
        LastScore as ( SELECT Entities.ID, Results.Score,
                             Results.UTC,   
...


SELECT *
FROM dbo.Func1(@Country)                    F1
CROSS APPLY dbo.Func2(F1.OrganizationID, F1.MeasurableID) F2
```

Comment: AWESOME!  Functions and CROSS APPLY worked like a charm!  Thanks again.

Comment: Following on this question, the Cross Apply was running 15-18 seconds (for what is still a development/tiny sized Azure hosted database).  So I moved the results of the first function into a UserDefinedType: Table and was able (including reducing size of some tables) to get the results down to 2 seconds.  However, a next requirement is to be able to specify results only from a list of currencies.  I created a UDT: Table for the currencies and can pass that to the function BUT for four (4) MeasurableIDs  and four (4) currencies am back up to 18 seconds.  

Any ideas?